# I'm not quite sure I understand this one. Show that the specified real number is rational: $7^{2/3}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rationality-testing

This is the first problem in this discrete math assignment, and I'm a little bit confused because I thought that the square root, cube root, nth root of a non-square, non-cube, etc. were not rational numbers. Is that untrue, and if so I don't even know how to start working on this one. Just as a reference, this problem is from the book *Discrete Mathematics and Applications* by Kevin Ferland p. 175 #2.
! [image]

Comment: I mean, this is obviously an irrational number.

Comment: That number is not rational. There's a miscommunication somewhere. Can you post an image of the problem?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but the book says to show that it is rational.

Comment: The reasoning is as usual. If $7^{2/3}=a/b$ then $7^2b^3=a^3$, and the exponents of $7$ in prime decompositions of LHS and RHS are different ($3k+2$ vs $3m$).

Comment: This is not a power. It is $7+2/3$.

Comment: That's the "mixed number" $7 + \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: How do you figure? I don't see an addition sign, but to me it looks like a superscript.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I haven't seen numbers written like that in I don't know how long. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: This is how mixed numbers are written. See https://www.mathsisfun.com/mixed-fractions.html

Comment: A superscript would be typeset higher in the page so that it is to the upper right of the base.  This is directly to the right and not elevated at all.   It is very common, acceptable, and conventional to have mixed frations such and "one and a half" as $1\frac 12$ and "9 and five eighths" as $9\frac 58$.  I'm surprised you aren't familiar with this.

Comment: @Hayden lol yea I haven’t seen numbers written like that since I was in kindergarten/elementary school. Right now if I see that hand written, or in a math paper somewhere my first instinct would be to regard it as multiplication.

Comment: I'm used to seeing numbers like this written as ${23}/3$.

Comment: Depends on context and what is being expressed.  If its a context that has more quantitative measurement value walking $7\frac 23$ miles is a lot more meaningful than $\frac {23}3$ miles.  In theoretic math where the numbers themselve (and not the quantity they represent) are more important there is almost no need for $7\frac 23$.  But that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.   Heck!  $CXLI$ is *still* a real number.

Answer (score 0):

Proof that the number $7^\frac{2}{3}$ is irrational:

Suppose otherwise, i.e. that $7^\frac{2}{3} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b$ are integers such that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. Then we may write

$$49b^3 = a^3$$

Which implies $7 | a \iff a = 7k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \implies 49b^3 = 343k^3 \iff b^3 = 7k^3 \implies 7 | b$. That is, both $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $7$, which contradicts our supposition $\gcd(a,b) =1$ $\square$.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: No but I figured I'd leave it up for anyone interested...